# How does NSLog solve optimization bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-optimization

My app creates secondary thread by NSOperationQueue.
In main thread, it writes message in buffer which is global variable.
In secondary thread, it wait until message with new line character arrives.
It works well without optimization option.
It stays in while loop if I compile with any optimization option(-O1 ~ -Os).
But if I write NSLog inside loop, it works.
What is problem of this?
Is there better way I can solve this problem without using NSLog?

```
while (!strchr(buffer, '\n')) {
    NSLog(@"!");   // without this, in optimized mode, it stays in while loop.
}
```

Comment: Are you building with Xcode > 3.2.6. If so, are you testing on a ARMV6 based device (iPhone 2G, 3G)?

Answer (score 5):

Your `buffer` is probably [not declared `volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#Example_of_MMIO_In_C). The compiler can assume no one else changes `buffer`, and turn the loop into:

```
char* res = strchr(buffer, '\n');
while (!res) {}
```

which could be an infinite loop.

With an NSLog, the compiler cannot assume NSLog won't mess with the globals, so the condition isn't factored out.

---

If you want to wait for another thread to be ready, please at least use condition variable ([NSCondition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html)) instead of an infinite loop.  Or maybe re-architect the code base to use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1).

Comment: I didn't write volite. I changed my code to volatile char buffer[64]. Compiler warns Passing 'volatile char []' to parameter of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers. How do I change?

Comment: volatile does not work. Instead, I enclosed while loop by         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex). It works. I don't know about NSCondition. Is NSCondition better than pthread? And if I use NSCodition, don't I have to use loop?

Comment: After I compile again, it does not work again. Pthread was not solution. At first, I thought volatile could solve the problem. I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: @user1071621: `volatile` is like `const`, if you apply it on one place, you need to apply it on others as well.